# Why are there so many different calling conventions?

Tags: assembly, history, low-level, calling-convention

Historically, why does it seem like just about everyone and their kid brother defined their own calling conventions?  You've got C, C++, Windows, Pascal, Fortran, Fastcall and probably a zillion others I didn't think to mention.  Shouldn't one convention be the most efficient for the vast majority of use cases?  Is there ever any good reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The calling conventions you mention were designed over the course of decades for different languages and different hardware.  They all had different goals.  cdecl supported variable arguments for printf.  stdcall resulted in smaller code gen, but no variable arguments.  Fastcall could greatly speed up the performance of simple functions with only one or two arguments on older machines (but is rarely a speed up today.)

Note than when x64 was introduced, on Windows at least, it was designed to have a single calling convention.

Raymond Chen wrote a great series on the history of calling conventions, you can start [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040102-00/?p=41213).

Comment: I love the Raymond Chen article.  It answered a lot of questions.

Comment: Note that one of Raymond Chen's downsides to `__fastcall` (*To add insult to injury, the called function often spilled the register into memory because it needed to spare the register for something else*) is much more likely for **16-bit** fastcall.  32-bit mode (especially 32-bit addressing modes) make all 8 registers much more orthogonal, with only a few common instructions still needing a value in a specific register (like division and variable-count shifts, which is [why the x86-64 System V ABI avoids RCX until the 4th register arg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35619528/224132).)

Comment: But yes, modern CPUs with fast cache and efficient store-forwarding can hide much of the overhead of store/reload of stack args.  It's still not great, which is why 64-bit calling conventions pass args in registers.  (Also, x86-64 having more than twice as many registers that aren't tied up with a special purpose like stack pointer greatly alleviates the problems Raymond Chen pointed out; RISC machines with lots of registers universally use register-arg calling conventions.)

Answer (score 2):

Because historically everyone and their kid brother did define their own calling conventions. They were all created for different purposes and thus driven by different performance needs. For instance, C++ favours optimisations for passing the `this` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

- Some of them are more efficient regarding performance and others more efficient in code size.
- Some features (variable arguments count) are only supported with some conventions.

More Information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason is the underlying architecture of the microprocessor (or processor). Most languages start on a specific CPU, and get entangled a bit with that architecture. For example, the old Univac 1100 series computer didn't even have a call stack!

Another part of the reason is that is is not possible to foresee the best solution until you've tried several ways of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

They're created for different purposes, and with different optimization systems.

For instance, to reduce "Stack Overflow," (no pun intended) some people thought of various ideas to call function to make stack overflows impossible.

Another instance is the Lambda Calculus.  Not to be too vague, but in Lambda, functions may only pass one argument and return one value, and thus also need their own calling conventions.