# x86 Assembly pushad/popad, How fast it is?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, micro-optimization

Im just trying to make very fast calculation based programe in x86 assembly
but i need to push accumulator, counter and data register before calling procedure. Is faster to push them manualy:

```
push eax
push ecx
push edx
```

or just use,

```
pushad
```

and same with poping. Thanks

Comment: Agner Fog's tables put `pusha/popa` at just below 20 micro-ops on skylake, with latency numbers not even given. In comparison, each `push/pop` is 1-2 micro-ops for a register operand, 2-3 cycle latency, possibly multiple operations per cycle throughput.

Comment: There are practical reasons to not indiscriminately use `pushad`/`popad`. You cannot choose which registers to push and pop – it's all or nothing.

Comment: If you are trying to create very fast assembly version of some program, you should first write it in C or C++, and benchmark that, as a starting point. Whatever you try, benchmarking/profiling is super important, and ideally in the real-use scenario, so you will benchmark also all cache/memory limitations. Artificial benchmarks are super easy to write+execute wrongly, getting skewed results not representing true performance of code. Anyway, programming for performance without profiling is wrong practice, and on x86 specifically it is near impossible, due to the very complex nature of x86.

Comment: push and pop performance should be mostly determined by the memory access time, yes? hit or miss, what level cache if any catches it.  for pushes is there a write buffer that consumes it? what are the differences when the write buffer is full  or when it has space, etc?

Comment: just push only the registers you need to push. you also can push one register and pop it to another. I would not recommend `pusha`/`popa`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If you care about performance, `pusha` / `popa` are almost never useful**.  They're only useful when optimizing for code-size at the expense of speed, e.g. to save/restore registers around a function.  But it's pretty inconvenient for non-`void` functions, because they reload *all* registers, so you have to store the return value in memory (e.g. over the stack slot that will be loaded into `eax`, or somewhere else to be reloaded after `popad`).

**Only push the registers that need saving**, or that you want to pass as function args.  Or, in [inline-assembly](/questions/tagged/inline-assembly), just let the compiler manage registers for you by declaring `"=r"(dummy1)` dummy output operands for any temp regs, or use clobbers on specific registers.  Normally the compiler can pick registers that it can let you clobber without saving.  (Or in the clunky MSVC-style inline asm, the compiler can't allocate registers for you, so you have to pick manually.  The compiler parses your asm to find clobbers.)

You normally don't need to save/restore `eax`; for performance you should probably `mov esi, eax` / call / use the value in `esi`, if you can't calculate the value in `esi` in the first place.  **i.e. use call-preserved registers for values that need to survive a `call`**, so a store/reload of your important value isn't on the critical path.  Instead, the store/reload is on the critical path of one of the caller's call-preserved registers which you (or the compiler) `push`/`pop` around the whole function, outside of any loops.

See more about [call-preserved vs. call-clobbered registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers/56178078#56178078) and how saving/restoring should normally work.  And what makes a good calling convention, e.g. [how x86-64 System V was designed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86/35619528#35619528), and also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707228/why-not-store-function-parameters-in-xmm-vector-registers) about how many args should be passed in registers, and why not also use XMM registers for integer args.  Of course, helper functions can use custom calling conventions.

---

### `pusha` / `popa` are slow on most CPUs

**Even if you did want to push all 8 integer registers (including `esp`!)**, using 8 separate `push` instructions is actually faster on modern CPUs.  pusha/popa are microcoded, [which can be a problem for the front-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907523/branch-alignment-for-loops-involving-micro-coded-instructions-on-intel-snb-famil).  (Although 8 single-byte instructions could be a problem for the uop-cache, too.  But in real code, you usually only need to push a few registers, not all of them.)

If you're optimizing for obsolete CPUs (like original in-order Pentium, and Pentium II/III), pusha/popa are as fast as 8 `push r` or 8 `pop r`, and actually fewer uops, because they didn't have a stack engine to eliminate the ESP-update uops.

From [Agner Fog's instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize/): modern CPUs have single-uop `push reg` and `pop reg`, because those instructions are used all the time by compilers and thus are important for performance.  push/pop throughput typically matches store/load throughput (often 1 store per clock or 2 loads per clock).  But `pusha` / `popa` are not used by compilers, so CPU designers don't have special support to make them fast.  `popa` throughput is limited to only 1 load per clock if *just* running `popa`.  (I think on Intel CPUs, the most likely explanation for the measured performance is that `popa` doesn't use the stack engine, so it bottlenecks on a dependency on `esp`.)

Intel:

- Skylake: `pusha`: 11 uops, 8c throughput.  `popa`: 18 uops / 8c throughput.
- Sandybridge: `pusha`: 16 uops / 8c throughput.  `popa`: 18 uops / 9c throughput.
- Nehalem: `pusha`: 18 uops / 8c throughput.  `popa`: 10 uops / 8c throughput.
- Silvermont/KNL: `pusha`: 10 uops / 10c throughput.  `popa`: 17 uops / 14c throughput.
- Pentium4:  `pusha`: 4/10 uops / 19c throughput.  `popa`: 4/16 uops / 14c throughput.
- P5 Pentium 1 / MMX: 5-9 cycles, non-pairable.  "9 if SP divisible by 4 (imperfect pairing)."

AMD: `pusha`/`popa` are surprisingly good on some AMD CPUs, especially K8.

- Ryzen: `pusha`: 9 uops, 8c throughput.  `popa`: 9 uops, **4c throughput**.  (Unlike Intel, AMD's new design has `popa` no worse than 8x `pop`.)
- Jaguar: `pusha`: 9 uops / 8c throughput.  `popa`: 9 uops / 8c throughput.  (Jaguar can only do one load per clock normally.)
- Piledriver: `pusha`: 9 uops / 9c throughput.  `popa`: 14 uops / 8c throughput.  (Agner lists regular `pop reg` throughput as 1 per clock for Bulldozer-family, although I think they do have a stack engine and can do 2 loads per clock.  Maybe the stack engine can only handle one stack instruction at a time?)
- K8:  `pusha`: 9 uops / 4c throughput!! (IDK how this is possible, either this is an error or typo in the table, or K8 merges 32-bit registers and does four 64-bit stores).  `popa`: 9 uops / 4c throughput.  These numbers do seem to be real: [InstLatx86 measurements](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/AuthenticAMD0000F4A_K8_Clawhammer_InstLatX86.txt) agree with 4c throughput for `pushad` / `popad` on Clawhammer (the first-gen K8 microarchitecture).  So clearly AMD put some effort into optimizing `pushad`.

---

You tagged this [inline-assembly](/questions/tagged/inline-assembly).  Usually you should avoid using `call` in inline-asm, so the C compiler knows about the call.

And let the compiler worry about registers; just tell it which ones you modify (GNU C `asm("..." ::: "eax", "ecx")` or whatever), or in MSVC-style inline asm it parses your asm and knows which registers were written.  If that includes any call-preserved registers, the compiler will save/restore those at the start/end of the whole function, even if the asm statement is in a loop.  (It might need to spill and/or reload some local vars before/after the asm statement or block, but would use mov, not push/pop for that.)

Comment: Also should be mentioned that PUSHA/POPA don't exist in 64 bit mode, so porting your code to this architecture would be more difficult in the future.

Comment: @vitsoft: I left that out because x86-64 uses a different calling convention anyway, with different call-preserved vs. call-clobbered registers.  e.g. in the x86-64 SysV calling convention, the only 2 non-new registers that are call-preserved are RBX and RBP (not counting RSP, which is also call-preserved of course).  So you'd have to revisit your pushes / pops anyway (at the very least to change all the register names from `eax` to `rax` if you really do want to save/restore everything).  But yes, worth mentioning as part of the evidence of it being old and obsolete.

Comment: Sure, but x86-64 calling convention concerns OS ABI invokations only. If my routine is private, it may call ip

Comment: Sorry, this stupid Android SO client won't let me edit or erase prematurely sent comments 

Comment: @vitsoft: yeah that's true.  You can use a register-arg convention in 32-bit mode for private helper functions, and clobber or preserve whatever is convenient.

Comment: are the CPUs between i386 and Pentium the same as P1~P3?

Comment: @crazii: no! https://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~fpf/Uebungen/GdR-SS02/opcode_i.html has 8086 to Pentium numbers (not including code-fetch bottlenecks [which are a big deal for 8088 especially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400133/increasing-efficiency-of-binary-gray-code-for-8086), not really relevant for pusha/popa which do tons of memory access for 1 byte of code).  Original Pentium and Pentium MMX is the P5 microarchitecture, dual-issue in-order.  I guess you could call that Pentium 1.  Pentium 2 / 3 are derivatives of Pentium Pro, 3-wide out-of-order, ancestor of Core2 / Nehalem.