# Multiple arguments by value or pointer to struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack, micro-optimization

Let assume this struct:

```c
typedef struct mytest_t {
    uint8_t field1;
    uint32_t field2;
    uint64_t field3;
    uint64_t field4;
    uint16_t field5;
    uint32_t field6;

} mytest_t;
```

And some function which want to create this struct (a little bit like an object):

```c
int something_with(uint8_t field1, uint32_t field2, uint64_t field3, uint16_t field5) {
    mytest_t *object = malloc(sizeof(mytest_t));

    object->field1 = field1;
    object->field2 = field2;
    object->field3 = field3;
    object->field4 = 0x12345678;
    object->field5 = field5;
    object->field6 = 42;

    dosomethingwith(object);
    return 0;
}

void initial() {
    something_with(123, 456, 789, 456);
}
```

Theses functions are purely made for example of my situation. This function is like a helper to have a single point in the code where object is filled then forwarded to something else.

**Note: this example is quite small, assume arguments would be 2 or 3 times longer.**

To avoid passing lot of argument to the function, and make call really long and difficult to read, I was thinking about passing a pre-filled `mytest_t` struct as argument (let assume needed fields are correctly filled).

Would it be better to pass the struct as value or pointer ? What's the cost of dereferencing all the field ? Does that do any difference since everything is on the stack ? Could the compiler optimize that in some way ?

```c
void initial() {
    mytest_t source = {
        .field1 = 123,
        .field2 = 456,
        .field3 = 789,
        // field4 not needed
        .field5 = 456,
        // field6 not needed
    };

    call_by_value(source);
    call_by_ptr(&source);
}

int call_by_value(mytest_t origin) {
    mytest_t *object = malloc(sizeof(mytest_t));

    object->field1 = origin.field1;
    object->field2 = origin.field2;
    object->field3 = origin.field3;
    object->field4 = 0x12345678;
    object->field5 = origin.field5;
    object->field6 = 42;

    dosomethingwith(object);
    return 0;
}

int call_by_ptr(mytest_t *origin) {
    mytest_t *object = malloc(sizeof(mytest_t));

    object->field1 = origin->field1;
    object->field2 = origin->field2;
    object->field3 = origin->field3;
    object->field4 = 0x12345678;
    object->field5 = origin->field5;
    object->field6 = 42;

    dosomethingwith(object);
    return 0;
}
```

My first assumption would be passing as value would just duplicate everything on the stack and don't give any benefit, but could dereferencing the object for each field be more expensive than duplicating it ? Would the pointer version not maybe ends in a lot of cache miss and the stack version not ?

Comment: you could just measure the difference in performance between the two alternatives.

Comment: It depends on your architecture, in many cases, I would expect passing a pointer to be better in terms of performance. But: Passing the whole value can have architectural benefits. You can work with immutable objects, for example.

Comment: My empirical rule is: if sizeof(type) > 2*sizeof(void*), I prefer passing a pointer.

Comment: @FelixPalmen in that case, it would be x86_64 mostly

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I would like a more generic answer than « on my machine it's faster »

Comment: @Maxux : I'm afraid a generic answer is unlikely - a lot depends on the hardware, the compiler, the compiler flags, etc. The best you can hope for is a rule of thumb like Alex F's above.

Comment: Why is it that you want to create a new dynamic `mytest_t` and copy all fields if you already have been passed a `mytest_t`.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Yeah I know, it was looking for some technical details for hardware, not a single response working for all of them :)

Comment: @4386427 If you look closer, you will see all fields are not already pre-filled. The function which allocate the dynamic one allocate some field itself. This is a really small example, in reality, the dynamic object have lot of fields computed/filled on the fly, and some of them are passed via arguments.

Comment: You can try using the [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org) to compare the generated code for both of your examples. Remember to benchmark as well to make sure this kind of optimisation will actually affect your performance!

Comment: @Maxux The types are the same so the fields are already there. You can simply initialize the so far uninitialized fields in the passed argument instead of creating a new dynamic variable. Creating a dynamic variable is (most likely) far more expensive than all other code posted.

Comment: @4386427 The dynamic variable is then pushed in a heap allocated list, it can't stay on the stack.

Comment: @Maxux ok, if it really has to be dynamic fine. But then your performance considerations are most likely useless. The dynamic allocation will (most likely) be far more expensive than the initialization - regardless of passing by value or passing a pointer. In other words: I think you are trying to optimize something that really takes just a few percent of the total execution time. It's most likely not worth it. Just do it the way you find your code most readable and maintainable.

Comment: The ABI defines how parameters of struct type are passed and returned; you could look up the ABI spec for the platform you are interested in

Answer (score 2):

From what it sounds like your number of struct members will exceed the number of parameters that can be passed in parameters (at least on any architecture's calling convention I have come across); causing the remaining values to be placed on the stack anyhow.  That is not much different than passing the struct by value entirely on the stack.  This can cause even more copying around than if you just allocated it on the stack to begin with and then passed a pointer.

That leaves you with a few options depending on how your structs will be used.  For example:

- <del>Alex F mentioned a rule of thumb `sizeof(type) > 2*sizeof(void*)` (Many calling conventions allow for those "small structs" to be passed in registers)  You are way past that and past the number of parameters that can be passed in registers.</del>
- If you need to support multiple architectures AND your struct is more than a few members (see thumb-rule above), a pointer to struct is the best simple option.
- If your struct could be easily split into commonly used members and uncommon ones, you could split it up into a hot and cold struct or a struct with a small number of hot members and a cold struct (or union of structs) containing the cold members.  (See example below)

I mentioned the possibility that the "cold" struct possibly be a union of structs.  This can be useful if many of the members are superfluous depending on one of your "hot" members (see a html/dom parser for examples)  If that can get more of your structs to fit inside a cache line, you get the benefit of better cache locality and a reduced memory footprint (maybe - depends on how many instances of the struct there will be - is it just a context struct or will there be an array or linked list of them?).  I wouldn't necessarily recommend adding this complexity unless profiling indicates its a bottleneck or the cause of excessive resource usage.

```
struct mystruct {
  struct hot{ long node_type; struct mystruct *next;} hot;
  struct cold{ /* the rest of your members */ } cold;
}
void myfunc(struct hot x, struct cold *y);
//or
struct mystruct {
  long node_type; //hot
  struct mystruct *next; //hot
  struct cold{ /* the rest of your members*/ } cold;
}
void myfunc0(struct mystruct *next_node, long node_type, struct cold *y);
void myfunc1(long node_type, struct cold *y);
```

On a side note, your struct, as demonstrated, will have a lot of useless padding (or require inefficient unpacking if "packed")  If you order your members from largest to smallest it will pack a lot better.  Unless the size of the struct exceeds cache line size (typically ~64 bytes these days), there is little to no impact if smaller members are separated from larger members that they are commonly used with.  For more insight see [The Lost Art of Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/).

Edit:

Once you have your struct sorted by size, it may be that your members would conveniently fit in SIMD registers and may even be conducive to SIMD operations.  Arm's typedefs seem to be consistent with standard naming conventions and convenient to use on compilers that support [vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html).

Here is a relatively portable version of arm's vectors for 128 bit

```
typedef __INT64_TYPE__    int64x2_t   __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
typedef __UINT64_TYPE__   uint64x2_t  __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
typedef __INT32_TYPE__    int32x4_t   __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
typedef __UINT32_TYPE__   uint32x4_t  __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
typedef __INT16_TYPE__    int16x8_t   __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
typedef __UINT16_TYPE__   uint16x8_t  __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
typedef __INT8_TYPE__     int8x16_t   __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
typedef __UINT8_TYPE__    uint8x16_t  __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
typedef double            float64x2_t __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
typedef float             float32x4_t __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
///similar for vector sizes 32 and 64
```

As an example for x86_64 you could pass (u)int64_t in the integer registers and, using 8 SIMD registers, an additional combination of 128 char types, 64 short, 32 int or 16 long (or even more with AVX2 or AVX512 support).  That's not to say it will be any faster though if the data is not conducive to SIMD operations.  It will depend on the usage patterns.

Comment: (nvm, just saw the part where the OP says assume >2 times bigger than 6).  x86-64 System V, used on all x86-64 systems except Windows, [passes the first 6 integer args in registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6/2538212#2538212) (and also the first 8 FP args in XMM registers).  Many other calling conventions only use 4 arg-passing regs, like 32-bit ARM (and `uint64_t` takes 2 regs there), but I'm not sure about AArch64.  I wouldn't be surprised if some 64-bit RISC calling conventions use more than 4.

Comment: @PeterCordes The question said 2-3x the given 5 (or 6 - it wasn't consistent) members (so I was assuming 10-18) ... I almost mentioned using SIMD registers, but the members all appear to be random types and it wouldn't be portable without behind the scenes work.

Comment: Yup, I typed all but the start of that comment before seeing the 2x-3x part of the question.  I had been just responding to the first line of your answer based on 6 members.  Anyway, you *could* pass multiple int args packed into SIMD registers, but as you say, you're just making things worse if they need to be used separately (or if the callee won't actually use all of them).  I wrote an answer on [Why not store function parameters in float registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33707228) a few years ago.

Comment: Totally agree it depends on the surrounding code and exactly what the caller and callee are doing.  But most likely sorting the struct by size and passing by ref will be best for 12 or more members.  **Definitely a case where you want to enable link-time optimization so the compiler can inline (even across compilation units) and optimize away unnecessary copying.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I guess that at the end, the compiler anyway will try to optimize things to take advantage and it would be interesting to see what it produces to know better.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you're going to use always the same value, then a pre-filled mytest_t struct would be the better choice...BUT if you think you'll change the values at some point inside another function, then...pass the poiner to the pre-filled mytest_t is better.

For the compiler (and OS) is better when you pass the adress (pointer) because he doesn't need to ask OS for more memory, he already have what he needs (the pointer and values).

Your only concern should be...DON'T LOSE YOUR POINTER, and always know what you're changing when you update any data.