# internal registers, difference between temporary and argument-registers

Tags: c, assembly, riscv, calling-convention, mcu

Regarding an MCU with RISC-V. I have this MCU: RV32IMAC with 32 internal registers, including temporary registers (t0-t6), argument/return registers (a0-a1), and argument registers (a2-a7).

What would happen or what problems would one encounter if only t-registers were available, without any a-registers? I know C, so comparisons can be related to the programming language.

Comment: When you run out of registers, you typically start using the stack. (Or well, the C compiler does that in case you are writing C.)

Comment: How the function memry frame and registers are manged is described by ABI - you need to find the one for your micro and OS.

Comment: If only t-registers were available, you'd define a different calling convention where you return in `t0` or `t1:t0`, and pass args in up to 2 or 3 regs.  Maybe 4 to 6 arg-passing regs if you still had some call-preserved `s` registers, not a tiny machine with only 7 total registers that's cramped like x86.  If you have more args than that, you'd pass the rest on the stack.  You *could* return on the stack instead of registers, like the inefficient calling-convention Go uses.  See also [What's the advantage of having nonvolatile registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47206975)

Comment: The "a" registers are used for passing parameters for functions and for function return values. Without them you'd have to do those things differently, like using "t" registers for those operations, or, like using stack memory for them.

Comment: Alright, when does the t-args get "destroyed"? Could this happen whenever and why does it happen?

Comment: There's no such thing as "t" args, so you'll have to rethink your question.  The "t" registers are potentially wiped out by calling a function, and of course, that's also true for the "a" registers.  Only the "s" registers (along with the stack pointer register, and the global & thread pointer registers) are guaranteed to be preserved by calling a function.

Comment: The "a" registers might necessarily be repurposed by the caller itself during set up of a call, i.e. parameter passing (`f(1)` requires a 1 in `a0`), which happens *before* the transfer of control flow (branching) to the callee, whereas the "t" (and "a") registers may be repurposed *during* the execution of the callee.  (The "s" registers may be repurposed by a callee, but if they are, they must also be first preserved and later restored prior to returning to its caller.)

Comment: Registers never get "destroyed" — they simply hold their last written value.  By the calling convention, some registers (scratch-registers) can be overwritten and repurposed without regard to some caller's prior value therein; while other registers (call-preserved) can also be repurposed as long as their original values are restored prior to return to caller.  (The hardware doesn't care though, viewing most all registers as the same.)

Comment: https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/riscv-calling.pdf