# What registers need preserved in Microsoft x86-64 Calling convention?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I cant seem to find what registers need to be preserved in the x86-64 Microsoft calling convention. I understand the first 4 parameters are in rcx/rdx/r8/r9 (Assuming non-floats). But what other registers do I need to preserve/if any?

For example in CDECL I have to preserve EBX/EDI/ESI. Is there any such notion in x86-64, or can I simply use any of the available registers?

x86-64 Microsoft (Windows x64) is a different calling convention than the x86-64 System V ABI: [Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86)

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx

Comment: Harold has the actual answer.

Comment: Thanks Harold! I cant mark it as the answer since it was posted a comment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was provided by [harold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555045/harold) as a comment, but moving it here so I can mark it as the answer:

[x64 Calling Conventions - Register Usage](https://web.archive.org/web/20170222171451/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx)