# nasm 64, segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, nasm

I'm trying to copy array A to array B. 
Here's my cpp file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void copy(int * to, int * from, unsigned int n); //_Z6copyPiS_j

int main(){
  int * a = new int [4];
  int * b = new int [4];
  for (int i=0;i<4;++i)
  {
    a[i] = i+1;
  }
  kopiuj(b,a,4);
  for (int i=0;i<4;++i)
  {
    printf("%d - ", b[i]);
  }
  delete(a);
  delete(b);
  return 0;
}
```

and here is my asm file with copy function implementation

```
BITS 64
section .text

global _Z6kopiujPiS_j

_Z6kopiujPiS_j:                  

push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
cld
mov edi,  dword [rbp+8] ; destination
mov esi,  dword [rbp+12] ; source
mov ecx,  dword [rbp+16] ; size

rep movsd; repeat ecx times


mov rsp, rbp
pop rbp
ret
```

here is how I compile it. Unfortunately it has to be 64 bit.(exercise requirement)

```
// nasm -felf64 82.asm -o 82.o
// g++ -m64 -o 82m.o -c 82m.cpp
// g++ -m64 82m.o 82.o -o 82
```

and at `rep movsd` I get segmentation fault. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: 64bit == pointers are 8 bytes: Why ebp+8/12/16..those are 4 apart? And what calling convention passes the first 3 args via the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be assuming the parameters are passed on the stack. The common calling conventions for x64 use registers for the first few parameters. See [Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86). (Or look at the generated assembly for the call to see how the parameters are passed.)

Comment: Thank you, that was my fault. First I wrote program for 32 bits and then tried to convert it to 64 and completely forgot about convention.