# x86-64 segmentation fault saving stack pointer

Tags: c, assembly, x86, cygwin, x86-64

I am currently following along with [this tutorial](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~kstew2/cs533/project/assign1/), 
but I'm not a student of that school.

GDB gives me a segmentation fault in `thread_start` on the line:

```
movq  %rsp, (%rdi)   # save sp in old thread's tcb
```

Here's additional info when I backtrace:

```
#0  thread_start () at thread_start.s:16
#1  0x0000000180219e83 in _cygtls::remove(unsigned int)::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll
#2  0x00000000ffffcc6b in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Being a newbie, I can't for my life figure out why. Here is my main file:

```
#define STACK_SIZE 1024*1024

//Thread TCB
struct thread {
    unsigned char * stack_pointer;
    void(*initial_function)(void *);
    void * initial_argument;
};

struct thread * current_thread;
struct thread * inactive_thread;

void thread_switch(struct thread * old_t, struct thread * new_t);
void thread_start(struct thread * old_t, struct thread * new_t);

void yield() {
    //swap threads
    struct thread * temp = current_thread;
    current_thread = inactive_thread;
    inactive_thread = temp;

    thread_switch(inactive_thread, current_thread);
}

void thread_wrap() {
   // call the thread's function
    current_thread->initial_function(current_thread->initial_argument);
    yield();
}

int factorial(int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1);
}

// calls and print the factorial
void fun_with_threads(void * arg) {
    int n = *(int*)arg;
    printf("%d! = %d\n", n, factorial(n));
}
int main() {
    //allocate memory for threads
    inactive_thread = (struct thread*) malloc(sizeof(struct thread));
    current_thread = (struct thread*) malloc(sizeof(struct thread));

    // argument for factorial
    int *p= (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 5;

    // intialise thread
    current_thread->initial_argument =  p; 
    current_thread->initial_function = fun_with_threads;
    current_thread->stack_pointer = ((unsigned char*) malloc(STACK_SIZE)) + STACK_SIZE; 
    thread_start(inactive_thread, current_thread);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my asm code for thread_start

```
# Inline comment
/* Block comment */

# void thread_switch(struct thread * old_t, struct thread * new_t);

.globl thread_start

thread_start:
  pushq %rbx           # callee-save
  pushq %rbp           # callee-save
  pushq %r12           # callee-save
  pushq %r13           # callee-save
  pushq %r14           # callee-save
  pushq %r15           # callee-save

  movq  %rsp, (%rdi)   # save sp in old thread's tcb
  movq (%rsi), %rsp    # load sp from  new thread

  jmp thread_wrap
```

and thread_switch:

```
# Inline comment
/* Block comment */

# void thread_switch(struct thread * old_t, struct thread * new_t);

.globl thread_switch

thread_switch:
  pushq %rbx           # callee-save
  pushq %rbp           # callee-save
  pushq %r12           # callee-save
  pushq %r13           # callee-save
  pushq %r14           # callee-save
  pushq %r15           # callee-save
  movq  %rsp, (%rdi)   # save sp in old thread's tcb
  movq (%rsi), %rsp    # load sp from  new thread
  popq  %r15           # callee-restore
  popq  %r14           # callee-restore
  popq  %r13           # callee-restore
  popq  %r12           # callee-restore
  popq  %rbp           # callee-restore
  popq  %rbx           # callee-restore
  ret                  # return
```

Comment: What is the value in the register `rdi` at the time you execute that instruction? The parentheses mean that you are *dereferencing* the pointer that it contains, so if the pointer is not valid, your code will segmentation fault.

Comment: @CodyGray the value should be the first argument to thread_start which is inactive_thread, a pointer to a struct thread?

Comment: Your code works for me.
Try including <stdio.h> and <stdlib.h>?

Comment: @user2214143: So check with a debugger that it holds what you expect it to hold.  See the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for tips on using gdb for asm, or use whatever debugger you prefer.

Answer (score 5):

You're on cygwin, right?  It uses the Windows x64 calling convention by default, not the System V x86-64 psABI.  So your args aren't in `%rdi` and `%rsi`.

The calling convention is Windows x64, but the ABI is slightly different: `long` is 64 bit, so it's LP64 not LLP64.  See [the cygwin docs](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/programming.html).

You could override the default with [`__attribute__((sysv_abi))` on the prototype](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html), but that only works for compilers that understand GNU C.

---

[Agner Fog's calling convention guide](http://agner.org/optimize/) has some suggestions on how to write source code that assembles to working functions on Windows vs. non-Windows.  The most straightforward thing is to use an `#ifdef` to choose different function prologues.

---

This [Intel intro to x64 assembly](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly) is somewhat Windows-centric, and details the Windows x64 `__fastcall` calling convention.

(It's followed by examples and stuff.  It's a pretty big and good tutorial that starts from very basic stuff, including how to use tools like an assembler.  I'd recommend it for learning x86-64 asm in a Windows dev environment, and maybe in general.)

> #### Windows x64 `__fastcall` (like x64 `__vectorcall` but doesn't pass vectors in vector regs)
>
> - **RCX, RDX, R8, R9 are used for integer and pointer arguments** in that order left to right
> - XMM0, 1, 2, and 3 are used for floating point arguments.
> - Additional arguments are pushed on the stack left to right.
> - Parameters less than 64 bits long are not zero extended; the high bits contain garbage.
> - It is the caller's responsibility to allocate 32 bytes of "shadow space" (for storing RCX, RDX, R8, and R9 if needed) before calling the
>   function.
> - It is the caller's responsibility to clean the stack after the call.
> - Integer return values (similar to x86) are returned in RAX if 64 bits or less.
> - Floating point return values are returned in XMM0.
> - Larger return values (structs) have space allocated on the stack by the caller, and RCX then contains a pointer to the return space when
>   the callee is called. Register usage for integer parameters is then
>   pushed one to the right. RAX returns this address to the caller.
> - The stack is 16-byte aligned. The "call" instruction pushes an 8-byte return value, so the all non-leaf functions must adjust the
>   stack by a value of the form 16n+8 when allocating stack space.
> - Registers RAX, RCX, RDX, R8, R9, R10, and R11 are considered volatile and must be considered destroyed on function calls. RBX, RBP,
>   RDI, RSI, R12, R14, R14, and R15 must be saved in any function using
>   them.
> - Note there is no calling convention for the floating point (and thus MMX) registers.
> - Further details (varargs, exception handling, stack unwinding) are at Microsoft's site.

**Links to MS's calling-convention docs in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki (along with System V ABI docs, and tons of other good stuff).**

See also [Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86)

Comment: For reference the calling convention is specified in the [Cygwin docs](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/programming.html) . It does in fact use the Microsoft x64 Calling convention. Cygwin differs from MinGW and Windows in that uses an LP64 data model instead of LLP64.

Comment: Ah, good catch on Cygwin! I saw that, but didn't think anything of it, because I figured it used the System V ABI, rather than the Windows one. Seems like a rather strange choice, considering they go out of their way otherwise to emulate the *nix behavior. I disagree with that Intel doc's choice to refer to the Windows x64 calling convention as "fastcall" through. Fastcall exists for 32-bit code, but is rather different in a number of significant ways than the x64 convention. They really only share the superficial design choice of passing some args in regs, so reusing the name is confusing.

Comment: @CodyGray: Cygwin uses the Windows ABI so it can call Windows libraries, and make libraries that can be called by Windows code.  Makes sense to me; it's POSIX source-compatibility layer, not a Linux binary-compat layer, and doesn't support `int 0x80` or `syscall` either.  (i.e. it's not WINE).

Comment: @CodyGray: It's weird, but [Microsoft calls it `__fastcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) for x64.  Although that page links to the 32-bit `__fastcall` doc, which says [*The `__fastcall` keyword is accepted and ignored by the compilers that target ARM and x64 architectures; on an x64 chip, by convention, the first four arguments* ...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk.aspx).  They definitely use `__vectorcall` for both the 32-bit version and 64-bit version of that, which have huge differences.

Comment: Yeah, I knew vectorcall was overloaded in meaning, but I hadn't seen any Microsoft documentation that used fastcall to refer to the x64 calling convention. That's rather too bad. Oh well, I guess it's of little surprise. Poor fastcall was always so overloaded in meaning as to be effectively meaningless for 32-bit builds. It was never standardized, and each vendor (MS, Borland, Watcom, etc.) implemented their own take on it. Microsoft's compiler ignores all calling convention specifiers but `__vectorcall` for x64 builds.

Comment: @CodyGray: heh, `__fastcall` was too tempting a name, I guess.  Or were they trying but failing to be compatible-enough to interoperate?

Comment: (off topic):  Outside of Windows, AFAIK there's still really only the 32-bit x86 System V ABI.  It's not good for performance (no register args), but at least it's pretty compatible! (except for the somewhat-recent addition of the 16B stack alignment requirement to the ABI, where it was originally 4B).   Unlike Microsoft cdecl or stdcall, x86-32 SysV won't return even small structs in edx:eax, and there's no version of it that uses XMM registers for passing/returning FP args at all, so FP returns have to be in st0.

Comment: (update: GCC does have an `-msseregparm` option to return FP args in XMM in 32-bit mode.  It's related to `-mregparm=3` which is also not ABI-compatible.)