# Why "mov rcx, rax" is required when calling printf in x64 assembler?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I am trying to learn x64 assembler. I wrote "hello world" and tried to call printf using the following code:

```
EXTERN printf: PROC

PUBLIC hello_world_asm

.data
hello_msg db "Hello world", 0


.code
hello_world_asm PROC
push rbp ; save frame pointer
mov rbp, rsp ; fix stack pointer
sub rsp, 8 * (4 + 2) ; shadow space (32bytes)

lea rax, offset hello_msg
mov rcx, rax ; <---- QUESTION ABOUT THIS LINE
call printf

; epilog. restore stack pointer
mov rsp, rbp
pop rbp
ret
hello_world_asm ENDP


END
```

At the beginning I called printf without "mov rcx, rax", which ended up with access violation. Getting all frustrated I just wrote in C++ a call to printf and looked in the disassembler. There I saw the line "mov rcx, rax" which fixed everything, but *WHY* do I need to move RAX to RCX ??? Clearly I am missing something fundamental.

Thanks for your help!

p.s. a reference to good x64 assembler tutorial is more than welcome :-) couldn't find one.

Comment: `rax` is volatile. `printf` uses `rcx` to load the string so in my understanding, it's just the calling convention you got wrong. Pretty good explanation [here](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=3101.0)

Comment: Because the first parameter to x64 printf goes in rcx, not rax.

Comment: See the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to docs and tutorials.  Since you're using Windows, https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly is probably a good one.

Comment: Not related to the question, but seems to me you could have loaded `offset hello_msg` into _RCX_ with `lea` rather than using _RAX_ as an intermediate step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It isn't required, this code just wastes an instruction** by doing an `lea` into RAX and then copying to RCX, when it could do

```
lea   rcx, hello_msg
call  printf              ; printf(rcx, rdx, r8, r9, stack...)
```

**`printf` on 64-bit Windows ignores RAX as an input**; RAX is the return-value register in [the Windows x64 calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877197/x86-64-segmentation-fault-saving-stack-pointer/40880663#40880663) (and can also be clobbered by `void` functions).  The first 4 args go in RCX, RDX, R8, and R9 (if they're integer/pointer like here).

Also note that FP args in xmm0..3 have to be mirrored to the corresponding integer register for variadic functions like `printf` ([MS's docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd2wa36c.aspx)), but for integer args it's not required to `movq xmm0, rcx`.

---

In the x86-64 System V calling convention, variadic functions want `al` = the number of FP args passed in registers.  (So you'd `xor eax,eax` to zero it).   But the x64 Windows convention doesn't need that; it's optimized to make variadic functions easy to implement (instead of for higher performance / more register args for normal functions).

**A few 32-bit calling conventions pass an arg in EAX, for example Irvine32, or `gcc -m32 -mregparm=1`.  But no standard x86-64 calling conventions do.**  You can do whatever you like with private asm functions you write, but you have to follow the standard calling conventions when calling library functions.

---

Also note that `lea rax, offset hello_msg` was weird;  LEA uses memory-operand syntax and machine encoding (and gives you the address instead of the data).  `offset hello_msg` is an immediate, not a memory operand.  But MASM accepts it as a memory operand anyway in this context.

You could use `mov ecx, offset hello_msg` in position-dependent code, otherwise you want a RIP-relative LEA.  I'm not sure of the MASM syntax for that.

Comment: `lea rax, offset hello_msg` would have assembled on every version of MASM and TASM I've ever used and that goes back to the 80s (of course with 16-bit addresses). MASM's use of brackets is optional so it would be the same as `lea rax, [offset hello_msg]` and the offset is effectively discarded, so is equivalent to `lea rax, [hello_msg]`

Answer (score 2):

The [Windows 64-bit (x64/AMD64) calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) passes [the first four integer arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx) in RCX, RDX, R8 and R9.

The return value is stored in RAX and it is volatile so a C/C++ compiler is allowed to use it as generic storage in a function.