# Why the linux read ip register from rcx register in the entry_SYSCALL_64 function?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls, cpu-registers

I'm studying system call handling process in linux.

I found that the entry_SYSCALL_64 function is called when the user process run syscall instruction to call system call.

This function save interrupt frame.

However, when it push the ip to interrupt frame, it read not rip but rcx.

This code is in blow.

```
ENTRY(entry_SYSCALL_64)
  UNWIND_HINT_EMPTY
  /*
   * Interrupts are off on entry.
   * We do not frame this tiny irq-off block with TRACE_IRQS_OFF/ON,
   * it is too small to ever cause noticeable irq latency.
   */

  swapgs
  /*
   * This path is only taken when PAGE_TABLE_ISOLATION is disabled so it
   * is not required to switch CR3.
   */
  movq  %rsp, PER_CPU_VAR(rsp_scratch)
  movq  PER_CPU_VAR(cpu_current_top_of_stack), %rsp

  /* Construct struct pt_regs on stack */
  pushq $__USER_DS      /* pt_regs->ss */
  pushq PER_CPU_VAR(rsp_scratch)  /* pt_regs->sp */
  pushq %r11        /* pt_regs->flags */
  pushq $__USER_CS      /* pt_regs->cs */
  pushq %rcx        /* pt_regs->ip ********************************** */
GLOBAL(entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe)
  pushq %rax        /* pt_regs->orig_ax */

  PUSH_AND_CLEAR_REGS rax=$-ENOSYS

  TRACE_IRQS_OFF

  /* IRQs are off. */
  movq  %rsp, %rdi
  call  do_syscall_64   /* returns with IRQs disabled */
  ....
```

I entered the so many '*' in important line.

In the comment, it saying that it save ip register and this offset is offset of ip correctly.

However, it read rcx....

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [the `syscall` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) stores the address of the instruction following `syscall` into RCX before entering the kernel.

Comment: Thank you so much!

It was so simple!

But, where is the code that save the rip to rcx.

Is that just CPU circuit?

Comment: @오준택 yes, what is described on the included link, how `syscall` operates, is single (from point of view of code) CPU instruction, implemented in the HW of chip (probably with several micro instructions, but that's implementation detail).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: @오준택: There's an AMD64 mailing list archive with some messages from kernel devs and AMD CPU architects when they were sorting out the design of `syscall` / `swapgs` / `sysret`.  Masking of `RFLAGS` (and saving the old `RFLAGS` into `r11`) was basically at the request of Linux kernel devs.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86/35619528#35619528 for links.  And BTW, saving to registers means `syscall` itself doesn't have to modify `rsp` or store anything to memory after switching to kernel mode.