# Passing Parameters in Assembly

Tags: function, assembly, parameters, objdump

I have this question that I need help on. I'm supposed to detect the password (the answer) to this problem which is one of the parameters in assembly.

Output:

In this level, you will need to use gdb to find the password as it is
being passed as a parameter to a function with 6 parameters. For x86-64,
the mnemonic for passing parameters using registers is Diane's Silk Dress
Cost $89. (rdi rsi rdx rcx r8 r9)

Enter the password:

The objdump code of the function I believe has the 6 parameters --

```
00000000004006a1 <foo>:
4006a1: 55                  push %rbp
4006a2: 48 89 e5            mov %rsp,%rbp
4006a5: 53                  push %rbx
4006a6: 48 83 ec 48         sub $0x48,%rsp
4006aa: 48 89 7d d8         mov %rdi,-0x28(%rbp)
4006ae: 48 89 75 d0         mov %rsi,-0x30(%rbp)
4006b2: 48 89 55 c8         mov %rdx,-0x38(%rbp)
4006b6: 48 89 4d c0         mov %rcx,-0x40(%rbp)
4006ba: 4c 89 45 b8         mov %r8,-0x48(%rbp)
4006be: 4c 89 4d b0         mov %r9,-0x50(%rbp)
4006c2: c7 45 e4 01 00 00 00 movl $0x1,-0x1c(%rbp)
4006c9: 48 8b 45 c0         mov -0x40(%rbp),%rax
4006cd: 48 89 c7            mov %rax,%rdi
4006d0: e8 5b fe ff ff      callq 400530 <strlen@plt>
4006d5: 89 45 ec            mov %eax,-0x14(%rbp)
4006d8: 8b 45 ec            mov -0x14(%rbp),%eax
4006db: 48 63 d8            movslq %eax,%rbx
4006de: 48 8b 45 b0         mov -0x50(%rbp),%rax
4006e2: 48 89 c7            mov %rax,%rdi
4006e5: e8 46 fe ff ff      callq 400530 <strlen@plt>
4006ea: 48 39 c3            cmp %rax,%rbx
4006ed: 74 07               je 4006f6 <foo+0x55>
4006ef: c7 45 e4 00 00 00 00 movl $0x0,-0x1c(%rbp)
4006f6: c7 45 e8 00 00 00 00 movl $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
4006fd: eb 31               jmp 400730 <foo+0x8f>
4006ff: 8b 45 e8            mov -0x18(%rbp),%eax
400702: 48 63 d0            movslq %eax,%rdx
400705: 48 8b 45 b8         mov -0x48(%rbp),%rax
400709: 48 01 d0            add %rdx,%rax
40070c: 0f b6 10            movzbl (%rax),%edx
40070f: 8b 45 e8            mov -0x18(%rbp),%eax
400712: 48 63 c8            movslq %eax,%rcx
400715: 48 8b 45 b0         mov -0x50(%rbp),%rax
400719: 48 01 c8            add %rcx,%rax
40071c: 0f b6 00            movzbl (%rax),%eax
40071f: 38 c2               cmp %al,%dl
400721: 74 09               je 40072c <foo+0x8b>
400723: c7 45 e4 00 00 00 00 movl $0x0,-0x1c(%rbp)
40072a: eb 0c               jmp 400738 <foo+0x97>
40072c: 83 45 e8 01         addl $0x1,-0x18(%rbp)
400730: 8b 45 e8            mov -0x18(%rbp),%eax
400733: 3b 45 ec            cmp -0x14(%rbp),%eax
400736: 7c c7               jl 4006ff <foo+0x5e>
400738: 8b 45 e4            mov -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
40073b: 48 83 c4 48         add $0x48,%rsp
40073f: 5b                  pop %rbx
400740: 5d                  pop %rbp
400741: c3                  retq
```

I believe from 4006aa to 4006be is the parameters. However, when I entered the values of those registers one by one individually as the answer, it said it wasn't the right answer (ex, -0x28). I tried inputting the answers in decimal, hex, and binary. I used gdb to debug it and print out the 6 parameter registers in the function and use those values gotten as the answer individually, it didn't work either. I'm stuck. Can I have some guidance on how to go about this problem?

note that I don't have access to the c code for this problem, or the assembly code written by a human. Only the objdump code, and the executable.

Here's the executable that I was given for this if you guys want to try it yourself to be able to help me out: https://www.mediafire.com/file/uglm044vw87lb11/ParamsRegs

Comment: That's an amusing mnemonic.  The way I remember the x86-64 SysV calling convention is that the args are set up so `memcpy` could inline as `rep movsb` ([rdi] <- [rsi]), but with rcx and rdx swapped because the calling-convention designer wanted to avoid using RCX for a fixed purpose in functions with only 3 args, because it has more required uses than RDX (e.g. shift counts).  (See [amd64.org mailing list archive links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86/35619528#35619528).)

Comment: Can you copy-paste `objdump` output without collapsing spaces?  That's *very* ugly to read vs. having all the mnemonics start at a consistent column.  Anyway, yes it has 6 args.  The compiler spills all the register args to the stack at the start of the function, so we can tell it was compiled in debug mode (and that there are 6 args).  I don't see any accesses to `8(%rbp)` or any other positive offset, so there aren't any stack args beyond the 6 register args.

Comment: @PeterCordes I like his mnemonic more than yours.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: Mine was never intended to be a memory aid, more like an additional fun fact about how the ABI was designed / why it makes sense once you do remember it.  (I'm lucky to have a good memory, so I tend to just remember things after having to look them up a couple times.  But having it make some kind of sense and connect with other things I know helps it stick.)

Comment: Sorry, @PeterCordes, I think you took my comment too seriously. :) :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: yes, apparently >.<  I agree the OP's mnemonic is more fun. :)

Comment: Line `4006d5` and `4006d8` is fun. And `4006c9` and `4006ce`. Is there any reason y the compiler did this?

Answer (score 2):

`4006e5: callq 400530 <strlen@plt>` calls a function to determine the length of a string.  It uses the same calling convention as your function, taking a `const char *` arg in RDI.  It's set here, from your 4th function arg:

```
4006b6: mov %rcx,-0x40(%rbp)
4006c9: mov -0x40(%rbp),%rax
4006cd: mov %rax,%rdi
```

This C standard library function returns the size of the string in `rax`.  Your function takes the low 32 bits of it and sign-extends that into `rbx` (presumably the source did `int len = strlen(arg4);`):

```
4006d5: mov %eax,-0x14(%rbp)
4006d8: mov -0x14(%rbp),%eax
4006db: movslq %eax,%rbx
```

At `4006de` to `4006e5` the same procedure is done again with another string set at `4006be: mov %r9,-0x50(%rbp)` and after this second call, the function compares the lengths:

```
4006ea: cmp %rax,%rbx
```

my guess is, that one of this strings is the password you are looking for and the other one is the string you put in. Just pause the execution at `4006a1`, print the registers with `info registers`, look at `rcx` and `r9` with `x/s <value in rcx/r9>`.

Or if the caller of this function parses your input into multiple string args, maybe with `scanf`, then those two words need to be the same length.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer because of you!