# why call glibc function crash without xor %rax, %rax?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

i call glibc function, for example, printf:

```
mov $some_string, %rdi
call printf   //<----crash
```

in some cases, such a call will crash. I add xor %rax, %rax this solves the problem.

I have two questions:

1. Why, in some cases, calling printf without xor %rax leads to a crash, and in some it does not?
2. Somewhere I saw such a call printf:

   ```
   lea  some_string(%rip), %rdi
   xor %eax, %eax
   call printf
   ```

Why this used rip register and how is this passing of an argument different from the usual?

Comment: 1) `printf` expects stack to be aligned to 16 bytes. If you don't do that, sometimes it will be aligned, other times it will not. If `eax` is not zero, `printf` will try to access arguments in `xmm` registers and may use instructions that require alignment. 2) that's just position independent rip-relative addressing

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714408/why-is-rax-not-used-to-pass-a-parameter-in-system-v-amd64-abi/52724015#52724015) describes how `%rax` is used for variadic functions, such as `printf`.

Comment: @Jester 1) hm, how to set align just for stack? not for all program
2) why write like that? Is there any reason?