# Where I should use "swapgs" instruction

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, x86-64, thread-local-storage

Hi I'm a kernel learner and have some questions about swapgs.

According to AMD's documentation, it swaps the `gs.base` hidden register and KernelGSBase MSR.

Furthermore, the addressing with "gs:XXXX" are calculated as "gs.base + base + (scale*index) + displacement"

---

Now my first question is:

1. gs.base is the hidden part of segment register
2. displacement is the "XXXX" part of "gs:XXXX"
3. index may be the selector index in gs

Then where I should store the "base" and "scale"?

---

Furthermore, where I should use it, my current project put upper half of the virtual memory space as kernel, and the compiler will not usually add "gs:XXXX" as addressing reference.

So where, in particular, I should use the `swapgs` instruction.

Comment: Base and scale are part of the memory addressing mode in the memory access instruction. The MSR (and gsbase) only contain the base of the gs segment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no hidden "base and scale", only a hidden `gs.base` that you use with a normal addressing mode.  (And a hidden value for the GS register itself.  That's a selector value, which would act as an index *into the GDT* if you actually did `mov gs, eax` instead of modifying just the GS base via an MSR, or via [`wrgsbase`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wrfsbase:wrgsbase).  But that's not related the the index part of the offset in a full `gs:[base + index*scale]` addressing mode).

You use `swapgs` in the kernel's `syscall` entry point handler, then use GS segment overrides on some loads and stores like you would for thread-local storage, so the previously-hidden `gs.base` is used *with* the `[base + idx*scale]` addressing mode you use in each load or store instruction.  e.g. something like `mov [gs:0x10], rsp` to save the user-space stack pointer and `mov rsp, [gs:0x18]` to load the kernel stack pointer.

**`swapgs` exists because `syscall` doesn't change RSP to point at the kernel stack** (and doesn't save the user-space RSP anywhere).  So you need some kind of thread-local (or actually core-local) storage so each core can get the right kernel stack pointer for the task running on that core.  The hidden GS base is storage for that hidden pointer, and a way to use it without destroying the values of any architectural registers.

You couldn't just use a regular global variable (absolute address) because that can only have one value that all cores would read.  You also don't have any spare registers (they all contain precious user-space state that you'll need to restore later), and you don't have a kernel stack to push them on.  And you can't use the user-space RSP; running `push` in kernel mode with the user-space RSP would let user-space crash the kernel by having RSP point somewhere invalid before running `syscall`.

---

When x86-64 was originally being designed (back in 2000, years before the first silicon), [this mailing list message](http://web.archive.org/web/20160729112540/http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2000-October/001009.html) explained the intended purpose of `swapgs`.  It was [revised a day later](http://web.archive.org/web/20160303170152/http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2000-October/001019.html) after OS devs noticed a problem with how AMD had specced it, but the original email contains a simple example that still applies:

> **Example usage**
> At a kernel entry point the OS can use SwapGS to obtain a pointer to kernel  data structures and simultaneously save the
> user's GS base. Upon exit it  can use SwapGS to restore the user's GS
> base:
>
> ```
>   SystemCallEntryPoint:
>     SwapGS                        ; set up kernel pointer, save user's GS base    
>     mov gs:[SavedUserRSP], rsp    ; save user's stack pointer
>     mov rsp, gs:[KernelStackPtr]  ; set up kernel stack
>     push rax                      ; now that we have a stack, save user's GPRs    
>     mov rax, gs:[CPUnumber]       ; get CPU number     < or whatever >
>     .                             ; perform system service
>     .
>     SwapGS                        ; restore user's GS, save kernel pointer
> ```

You might also want to look at how the Linux kernel uses it in its `syscall` entry point, preferably in older kernels before Spectre / Meltdown mitigation complicated everything.  e.g. [Linux 4.12's `entry_64.S`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7d0c41ecc2e372a81741a30894f556afec24315/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L100) has its `ENTRY(entry_SYSCALL_64)` start with `swapgs`, very much like AMD's example.

(See also [Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86/35619528#35619528) for some explanation of what happens in other Linux kernel entry points, from `int 0x80`).

Some of the comments in the Linux kernel source point out that it can be inconvenient to make sure `swapgs` runs exactly once along every path of execution out of the kernel.  If there were two opcodes, one for "swap to user gs" and one for "swap to kernel gs", it would be easier to make sure you don't accidentally swap an extra time.  That error would leave the next kernel entry looking in the wrong place.  (And give user-space the wrong gs, but in GNU/Linux `fs` is used for thread-local storage.)

Answer (score 4):

If your kernel doesn’t use gs to access kernel-private data, then you have no need to use this instruction. It is intended for a kernel to use upon entry to the kernel from user mode, to allow the kernel to save the application’s gsbase and load its own, without needing to access memory. The kernel can then save the application state in data structures referenced via gs.

Since you apparently have built your kernel to be able to save the guest state without using gs, you don’t need to use swapgs. You still may want to save and restore fsbase and gsbase on each context switch along with the rest of the application’s state so each user process can have its own value.