# X86-64 Registers with respect to function parameters

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

Does %rdi, for example, hold the value of the first parameter passed to the function in x86-64, or does it hold an address at which the value of the first parameter can be found? In other words, does %rdi hold the value of the first parameter or a reference to the parameter?

in other, other words, will I get the value of the first parameter if I do %rdi or (%rdi) in contexts such as mov or cmp?

Comment: It's the value, per the standard sysv abi convention.

Comment: The SYS V ABI will tell you the specific algorithm used. In general, if the argument can fit a register, it'll be in the register. It would make no sense to pass arguments in registers to only have to load them from memory. Of course, if you are passing a pointer the pointee will be in memory (but the pointer itself won't). Floating point args are passed in the XMM registers.

Answer (score 0):

First off, some languages pass arguments by reference by default, some pass by value. You didn't mention what language is it in.

C/C++ passes scalar arguments (`int`s up to 64 bits, pointers) by value, so it's %rdi. In the more general case, it depends on the argument's datatype.

Assembly programs are not, technically, bound by calling conventions, as long as it works. Tooling might be thrown off, but the choice to either adhere to the convention, tweak it, or come up with your own is there.

Also, the calling convention depends on the operating system. You don't mention which one you use, bur your mentioning RDI strongly suggests Linux. Here is a reference for the Linux x86-64 calling convention:

https://www.ired.team/miscellaneous-reversing-forensics/windows-kernel-internals/linux-x64-calling-convention-stack-frame

Comment: "Specifically for x86-64, IIRC, the integer argument/register correspondence is the same on all operating systems of note" What does it mean? Windows use a different calling convention for x64 than Linux, for example.

Comment: [Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4429398) - Windows is the odd one out.